# Can I ask chat content from myself be deleted (from history) in chatrooms?

Tags: support, chat

As in title, I think I have potentially said something I should not. Can I delete it forever? Or will the moderators help me?

Comment: ..everyone heads over to Python and Rust chatrooms to find out what it was that you should not have revealed..

Comment: If you're looking to get some sensitive information purged, I'd try using the [contact form](https://stackoverflow.com/contact).

Comment: You can always ask. The question you are trying to ask is, "would asking do any good?"

Comment: Flag any messages inside chat with the "flag for mod" option and explain what you want to happen. Mods are able to delete chat messages from rooms (although they remain visible to room owners and mods) and can if absolutely necessary, edit the content, purge the message history and then delete it which'll only leave the edited message in the history in case there was private/confidential information disclosed.

Comment: @Jon-Clements, but I have already clicked "delete the message" which leaves me no button of "flag for mod" to click on...I mean, it's still in the history but I want it removed completely

Comment: If you've self deleted it - then not too much can be done. The only people who could see it prior to deletion are room owners and they'd have to know where to look for it as the (removed) placeholder won't appear in the transcript and you can only load so many older messages to see that when in the room. Unless you posted your credit card number or social security details etc... I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Deleted chat messages hang around on the cached google search result page (and maybe archive.org) for **at least** a few days too.  (Same with deleted rooms.)